# Apache Server running but unable to access

Tags: networking, server, apache2, ssl

Just for reference, I followed these steps to attempt setting up an ownCloud server, as well as an SSL certificate.

- [How to Use iPhone with Linux (Guide).](https://beebom.com/how-use-iphone-with-linux/)
- [Enable and Configure SSL for ownCloud on Ubuntu for Secure Access.](https://www.avoiderrors.com/enable-ssl-owncloud-ubuntu/)

I'm a bit in over my head, the only goal here was to create a secure server in which I could occasionally transfer files from my phone to my computer and vice versa, and to expose myself to a bit of networking. I managed to set up the ownCloud server using xxampp, but I also wanted to encrypt the channel, so I set up a self-signed ssl certificate (entered my own information).

My Apache2 server is up and running according to `sudo service apache2 status`, but I have no way to access the website. I thought the URL would stay the same as before, only with the added **http(s)**.

Strange thing is, when I first entered that URL (`https://myip/myuser/owncloud`) I was greeted with the “this website isn't safe, certificate hasn't been verified” security notice, in which I was able to view my self-signed certificate. But after clicking “proceed at own risk”, the URL was found to be invalid. So I'm guessing that the URL is correct, but the website is having issues? Suggestions?

Comment: Is the website working OK via plain HTTP, without SSL?
Look into Apache error log to investigate the possible reason (there should be some directory called ```/var/apache/logs``` or ```/var/log/apache``` or something like this, and the file called ```error.log``` or ```error_log``` inside it).

Comment: @raj It's just giving me a 404 not found error. The error log states: `server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE` and `server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`. When I created my certificate, I never even entered an ID. Again, when I use `sudo service apache2 status` it says the server is up and running without problems.

Comment: Try to fix first the 404 error on HTTP. Something's must be wrong with your configuration; maybe ```DocumentRoot``` in your config file for "default" site is pointing to non-existent directory? Once your site works via HTTP, proceed to check HTTPS.